# how to remove space after each comma

Tags: notepad++

Hello this is a small part of my CSV file.

```
AQUA 1909 7444, AQUA 4318 8766, AQUA 4955 6282
```

As you can see there is a single space after each comma. I would like to know if there is a regex expression to find each blank space after the comma and delete it.

I tried to make a macro which just moves 4 words to the right and then remove but it seems to not work when repeating to the end of the file.

Many thanks in advance

I am using notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i don't have notepad++, but I believe something like

```
    search for: ,[ ]
    replace with ,
```

the ,[ ] says search for a comma followed by a space, if there is more than one space, you can change it to ,[ ]+ which says one or morespaces

Answer (score 1):

Search for regular expression

```
 ([,] )
```